# WCF MSMQ service not retrying when using transactional

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a wcf service that I am hosting within a windows service on a windows 2003 server that is listening on a MSMQ queue.  I set the ReceiveRetryCount = 2 on the netmsmqbinding.  The service was setup to use transactions ([OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete= true)]).  The service was functioning great.

I needed to turnoff the transactions due to a database call that couldn't support MSDTC.  So I switched the service properties to

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = false)]
```

Now, when an exception or fault is thrown, no retry occurs, the fault handler for the service never fires.  The original message ends up in the system DLQ.  I would like the fault handler to handle the faults after two retries.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch things back to the way they were before.

Around the database call, add the following (code is done from memory- let me know if I need to fix this up a bit):

```
// using System.Transactions;

using( var ts = new TransactionScope( TransactionScopeOption.Suppress ) )
{
  // Call DB stuff
  ts.Complete();
}
```